# Cannot convert ListBox Item to a Entity Database Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am building a Point of Sale system on ASP.net. I have a database table called "tblProduct" and I have used Entity Framework to convert it into a class using code first approach. I created a binding list, which holds  items, and have bound the ListBox datasource to the binding list. When a person selects a product, the item goes into the binding list and hence is displayed on the ListBox, everything works correctly up until now. My listbox name is "lbProductsChosen", just for reference.

```
private static BindingList<tblProduct> blProducts = new BindingList<tblProduct>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbProductsChosen.DataSource = blProducts;
            lbProductsChosen.DataTextField = "Description";
            CreateTab();
            AddProductsToTab();
            ButtonResize();
        }
```

However, while trying to make a "Delete" Button, to try and delete a selected item from the ListBox using:

```
protected void btnDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblProduct selectedItem = (tblProduct)lbProductsChosen.SelectedItem;
        blProducts.Remove(selectedItem);
    }
```

It gives me an error and tells me that it "Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'Restoraunt_POS.tblProduct'"

Edit: Here is my button click event, just for clarity. When a product button is pressed, it holds the information in its attributes properties, makes a new instance of the tblProduct class and puts it in the binding list(blProducts).

```
private void ProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            string description = b.Attributes["data-name"];
            decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(b.Attributes["data-price"]);
            int productID = Convert.ToInt32(b.Attributes["data-prodID"]);
            int prodType = Convert.ToInt32(b.Attributes["data-prodType"]);
            tblProduct p = new tblProduct() { Description = description , Price = price , ProductID = productID , ProductType = prodType };
            blProducts.Add(p);
            lbProductsChosen.Items.Clear();
            lbProductsChosen.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the tblProduct Model?

Comment: On the product button click events (which I have not added here, but guess I should have) I create a new instance of a class tblProduct and give it the corresponding values of the button. For example it makes a coffee, sets its price, etc., and adds this item to the binding list. Now when I add a few of these items, I want to be able to remove it from the listbox. I have actually seen it work except on a Forms application, which is the weird part. I will edit with my button click event.

Comment: In WebApplication Listbox.SelectedItem is not of type Object. It is of type ListItem which can't be converted to the binding Entity Type. You can access the Value and Text of the Item though.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I can see the selecteditem value, run it through the binding list with a loop and delete it that way?